How to block ip with ipv4 if the client's has ipv6 in PHP
I'm building a website with PHP and I want to configure it to only check the client's IPv4, but I'm having a problem that if the client has IPv6, it gets IPv6.
I get the IP with $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] but only get 1 single IP and prioritize getting IPv6. I want to only receive IPv4 in Apache by Listening to 0.0.0.0:80 but it doesn't work. Please give me a solution

If you don't want to get ipv6 connections then you must stop listening to ipv6

I tried but don't know how to bypass ipv6

To ensure that you only get the client's IPv4 address in PHP, you can use a combination of $_SERVER superglobal and a check for valid IPv4 addresses.
function getClientIPv4() {
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ipList = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
    foreach ($ipList as $ip) {
        $ip = trim($ip);
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {
            return $ip;
        }
    }
}

// Fallback to the remote address if no forwarded IP is valid
if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && filter_var($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

return null;
}

// Usage
$clientIPv4 = getClientIPv4();
if ($clientIPv4) {
    echo "Client's IPv4: " . $clientIPv4;
} else {
    echo "No valid IPv4 found.";
}

This function will check for IPv4 addresses in both the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and REMOTE_ADDR fields, ensuring you only get valid IPv4 addresses. If no valid IPv4 is found, it will return null.

Your function will just return null. Which makes it useless

I use it like that but only receive 1 ip from the client, but it prioritizes sending ipv6
